# Exporting data from an oracle DMP file

Tags: database, oracle, converters

Hope you can help out.
I got a DMP file from where i need some tables including the data. (preferable in XLS or separated CSV's)

I found out that it's a oracle database file so i installed oracle express.
Now i am trying to get the data imported en then, somehow, export the data to another format.

Is this the right way of doing this? or is there some kinda of tool to do the conversion.

when i try to import it with:

```
impdp system/retat file=c:\temp\data.dmp
```

i get the message:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39088: file name cannot contain a path specification
```

When i google errors i feel like i am over complicating the problem and tumbling from 1 problem to another. Is there an easy way?

Comment: There are two versions of the export utility (the Data Pump version and the classic version) so you'd need to use the corresponding version of the import utility.  You're using the Data Pump version of the import utility.  Do you know whether the export was done with the Data Pump version of the export utility or the classic version?

Comment: I think the IMPDP is correct. At least it did something. Now i am getting a shitload of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a database directory:

```
SQL> create directory temp_dir as 'c:\temp\';
```

And use impdp command like this:

```
impdp system/retat directory=temp_dir dumpfile=data.dmp
```

Comment: Allright! that is it! but now i get `Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed with 1792 error(s) at Tue Sep 22 16:45:59 2020 elapsed 0 00:00:08` alot of errors. starting with `ORA-39083: Object type USER:"TESTRUN" failed to create with error:
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name`       (why the hell can't i use enter's in my comments)